# How to get glare on “Quick Smoke” (Fire & Smoke explosion)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

FYI this is a duplicate of a message that i sent about a month ago, but i had no response and im desperate for an answer, so instead of people shutting down my question, please, i just need some help here.

I have this question that relates to Blenders Quick Smoke tool. Recently I have been rendering CGI explosions and smoke assets to be keyed in later on a short film, but I have this small problem that I think would make the explosion look a ton better, but I just cant quite figure out how to do it. Now as we may also know using composting, you can have a glare node on specific light sources to make the scene a lot more realistic, but Im trying to figure out how to do it with explosions. As seen below I rendered out this fairly simple explosion but I would really like it to have a glare to the flame parts of it.

[image]

Thanks if anyone has any ideas, also a quick side question as well, is there a way to hide the emitter (The sphere in the middle) [Cycles]. Thanks

Comment: Don't post duplicates please, think of [ways to improve your question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers) (e.g. Document the things you've tried in the month briefly.

Comment: Okay well yes, i have kind of given up on this, and there's no other ways that i can improve my question, all i need is an answer instead of people trying to shut down my question.